# Make a simple javascript timer

Tags: javascript

Hey i am trying to make a small 20 seconds timer for an application on the discord API(javascript)...I got many answers online but none seemed to prove succesful. Can anyone help me? This is the code I originally wrote

```
            setTimeout(function(){ var af = 0; while(af<21){ af = af+1;  if(af == 20){ break; } console.log(af);} }, 1000);
            message.reply("check the console"); // Part of the discord.js library...nothing to do with the timer
```

But the var af did not decrease by 1 every second...it became 20 in less than a second.. i.e the setTimeout() did not get followed..can u help me?

Comment: *"i.e the setTimeout() did not get followed"* - Yes it did. First there was a one second delay, then your function ran once with no further delays - which is exactly what `setTimeout()` is intended to do. Have you read any [documentation about JS timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers)? Why does your question have the "arrays" tag?

Comment: yes i read up a few JS timers documentations...but they didnt work in my code..the countdown happened once from 20 to 19 and then just stopped....Also sorry for that array tag..it was by mistake and i deleted it now.......But can you help me with this code? Like what change should i do to make it cuntdown the way i want it to?

Comment: You should format your code so it's readable and post it as a runnable snippet. It should not depend on external libraries, especially ones not supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. 
Do you want af to decrease or increase by 1 every second?

If you want af to be decreased by 1 every second starting from 20 and ending on 0.

```
 var af = 20; 

a = setInterval(function(){ 
console.log("Hi");
af = af-1;

if(af == 0){ 
    clearInterval(a);
 } 
console.log(af);
}, 1000);
```

This will call the function every second.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir..this one worked like a charm ..the var af get decreased every one second now..thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something every X second you can use setInterval.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  //code goes here that will be run every 1 seconds.    
}, 1000);
```

If you want to do something once but with delay you can use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
  //code will run after 30 seconds  
}, 30000);
```

So I guess you want to do something like this:

```
var af = 20;
function myTimer() {
  if(af === 0) {
    message.reply("check the console");
    clearInterval(timer);
  } else {
    af = af - 1;
    console.log(af);
  } 
}

var timer = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
```

Or just use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
  message.reply("check the console");
}, 20000);
```

Comment: Yes!! It worked...thank you!

Comment: If this is working for you mark the same as answer, this helps others to know, if the question has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script Src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="random_no_container">
Hello. Here you can see random numbers after every 60 sec
```

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
             /// U CAN DO YOUR CODE HERE
          var ran=Math.random();
          jQuery('#random_no_container').html(ran);
          }, 3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how the setTimeout method works, and to a greater extent how function execution works. Running the following code you have:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  var af = 0; 
  while(af<21){ 
    af = af+1;  
    if(af == 20){ break;} 
    console.log(af);
  } 
}, 1000);
```

The `setTimeout` calls the function after `1000` ms. Then is done its execution, only runs once. Furthermore, you have to consider what your function itself is doing; when its called after `1000` ms, it runs through the entire block, setting `af` to `0`, then looping until its `20` and then exiting, nothing about how its constructed maintains any persistance of `af`; after the function is completed `af` no longer exists. 
What you instead need to do is declare `af` outside the scope of the function that alters it, and only alter it once for each iteration. A common approach is to place `setTimeout` inside a function and recursivly call it untill the condition to stop has been met. Consider the following code:

```js
    var af = 0;
    function delayIncrementAF() {
        if(af == 20){return;}
        setTimeout(function () {
             af = af+1;  
             console.log(af);
             delayIncrementAF();
       }, 1000);
    }
    delayIncrementAF();
```

Comment: Oh i see...so setTimeout() calls the function after the specified time while setInterval() keeps executing the function every x seconds where x is the speicified time